# One of the div elements on my webpage is overlapping fixed header

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div element which is header and is fixed. I want it to remain at top of my website while other contents move below it while scrolling. 
Below this header is a div element containing two div elements, one is floated left while other right. 
Now when i scroll down my webpage left floated div element moves below the header as it should. However the other div element is moving over the header. I tried using z-index but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Can you add your code so we can help you ?

Comment: Add relevant html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the sample code to understand the problem.

Try adding z-index to the parent. Something like this

```
.fixed{
z-index:1;
}
.float-parent{
z-index:0;
}
```